# Browser with extensive caching options or add-on

Tags: windows, web-browser

Is there any browser, or add-on/extension for a browser that would let me cache content?

To clarify, I know most browsers already do cache content to an extent, however I am looking for something that can be customized with options similar to squid (the proxy).

It should at a minimum have options to configure the amount to store on disk (and where on the disk), in ram (and be able to save to disk upon close), and be able to over-write/ignore any expiry headers sent by the server.

I would prefer the software work on windows.

I know one solution is to use squid, however that is unable to (easily) cache secured content and would require extensive configuration to do so.

use cases:

1. I watch a youtube video (html5), but accidentally click away after it fully loads - I want to be able to quickly skip to where I was previously and have my browser access the "cached" object instead of downloading it all over again
2. I downloaded a file, then accidentally delete it - same thing, I want to be able to go to the download page, and pull it from the cache instead of from the internet
3. Images - while not as large as the others, images should be easy to cache and not require downloads

All of this needs to be automatic, so that I am not switching between online/offline mode - it can delete from the cache as needed when it starts to run out of room, but shouldn't (automatically) delete before then. Bonus points for if it has a "cache viewer" that can show me what urls/objects are currently cached and statistics on them (hit rate, most frequently used objects, etc.)

Comment: Firefox or so in offline mode? But for the actual use case, I am not so sure it can be solved like that. An even if it works for YouTube, it will not work for videos insisting on streaming. You may be better off using a stan-alone YouTube client, like `minitube`, or even [`youtube-dl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html "man page of 'youtube-dl' at manpages.ubuntu.com")

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - I want it to download stuff, but then not forget it once I close the tab (or even the browser) until it runs out of space in the cache (and then only delete the oldest entries, or least-recently accessed, etc.) - I suppose youtube may be more tricky if it's flash-based, but HTML5 should be fine to cache. I will add some more usecases to make it clear I hope.

Comment: Yes, I think that's how the browser offline mode works: You specify a large cache, and it tries not to delete anything as long as possible. It does not delete when closing the brower, and ignores lot's of cache specifications for sure. I'm curious whether the YouTube part works in the end - let us know!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - the problem with firefox's offline mode is "Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web." that it does not download anything in this mode - it won't ever fill its cache.